# pdfcrop results in fmtutils.cnf not found

Tags: texlive, debugging

I just tried `pdfcrop` but it results in an error message telling me that the file `fmtutil.cnf` was not found.

The complete error message is:

```
pdfcrop testfile.pdf
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdftex.fmt
/usr/local/bin/mktexfmt: 395: /usr/local/bin/mktexfmt: /texconfig/tcfmgr: not found
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
!!! Error: pdfTeX run failed with value 1!
```

`locate fmtutil.cnf` results in:

```
/usr/local/share/man/man5/fmtutil.cnf.5   
/usr/local/share/man/man5/fmtutil.cnf.man5.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man/man5/fmtutil.cnf.5
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man/man5/fmtutil.cnf.man5.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
```

I am using texlive on ubuntu 13.10 (manually installed):

```
tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 31673 (2013-09-16 18:03:22 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2013
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2013
```

Any idea how to fix this?

`echo $PATH` gives this:

```
/opt/texlive/2009/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/myuser/bin/aliases:/home/myuser/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

`which pdfcrop` gives `/usr/local/bin/pdfcrop`

and

```
ls -l $(which pdfcrop)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Jan  1 16:03 /usr/local/bin/pdfcrop -> /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/pdfcrop
```

`kpsewhich pdfcrop` results in nothing.

Comment: Can you add your `PATH` variable setting?

Comment: The `PATH` is wrong, you should change `/opt/texlive/2009` into `\usr/local/texlive/2013`

Comment: What's the result of `which pdfcrop`?

Comment: But it seems to be a correct symbolic link: `ls -lh /usr/local/bin/pdfcrop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Nov 22 16:20 /usr/local/bin/pdfcrop -> /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/pdfcrop`

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. However I noticed that your first suggestion already solved it. I just noticed that I misunderstood it. I changed `/opt/texlive/2009/bin/x86_64-linux` just to `/usr/local/texlive/2013` because I assumed tacitly that subdirectories are searched automatically. However changing it to `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux` just worked (even without removing the link). Perhaps you could turn your comments into an anwer. Then I can accept it and we can clean up the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have the correct value for the PATH variable:

```
/opt/texlive/2009/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/myuser/bin/aliases:/home/myuser/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

points to an old version of TeX Live and there's no trace of the new one. This might very well confuse the system. Change it into

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/myuser/bin/aliases:/home/myuser/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

If you have symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` for the TeX Live binaries, remove them: they won't do nothing good and possibly something bad. Of course this is a matter of opinion, so do what you think best.

I usually recommend adding a file in `/etc/paths.d` containing the only line

```
/opt/texbin
```

and creating a symbolic link

```
ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux /opt/texbin
```

so that when a new release is issued (say the 2014 one), you only need to do

```
rm /opt/texbin
ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux /opt/texbin
```

(with suitable privileges, of course) and you won't have to worry about changing configuration files nor doing any login-logout procedure.